# Puppet on windows

Tags: c#, windows, unix, puppet

I have puppet master on cent OS which is on VM on windows 2007.This acts as puppet master. Also I have installed puppet Enterprise as puppet agent installed on windows server 2008. But I don't know how should I point that server to cent OS client?

I am able to ping master VM from client machine and vice versa.

On Agent:

```
command :: puppet agent --test 
result :: Exiting; no certificate found and waitforcert is disabled
```

On Master:

```
command :: puppet cert --list 
result :: (Nothing)
```

Hence, Agent certificate request is not going to client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your puppet master is Puppet Enterprise also, otherwise a PE agent will not work with it.

The client needs to know where the puppet master is.  Can specify it on the command line with "--server fqdn.of.master" or put it in the agent's puppet.conf file in the main section.

I believe you'll find the puppet.conf file on Windows 2008 at c:\ProgramData\PuppetLabs\puppet\etc\puppet.conf

On Linux it's at /etc/puppet/puppet.conf

Comment: A am getting following error :: ----                          Warning: Unable to fetch my node definition, but the agent run will continue:
Warning: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not retrieve facts for xyz.com: Failed to find facts from PuppetDB at learn.localdomain:8081: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed:
 [certificate revoked for /CN=learn.localdomain]

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use puppetdb and don't have it configured properly.  More specifically the puppet master doesn't trust the certificate it's using.
If you're using Puppet Enterprise, PuppetLabs would be more than happy to give you direct assistance.  Since it looks like this is your first exposure and you're going down the Enterpise path, I would contact them.  They'd probably do a webex with you and walk you through getting it up and running.
[Puppet Enterprise Support](http://puppetlabs.com/services/customer-support)

Comment: please refer link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185963/could-not-retrieve-facts-from-inventory-service-ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0