# Could not retrieve facts from inventory service: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3

Tags: puppet, puppetlabs-apache

I can see following error in puppet Enterprise Console::

`Could not retrieve facts from inventory service: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server session ticket A: sslv3 alert certificate revoked`

Also I followed following steps::

1. I ran puppet agent -t on Windows puppet Enterprise client.
2. I ran puppet cert list and sign client certificate from master.
3. Again I ran puppet agent -t but I am getting following error on console ::

`Warning: Unable to fetch my node definition, but the agent run will continue: Warning: SSLconnect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: c ertificate verify failed: [certificate revoked for /CN=learn.localdomain] Info: Retrieving plugin Error: /File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/lib]: Failed to generate addit ional resources using 'evalgenerate': SSLconnect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv 3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed: [certificate revoked for /CN=learn.localdomain] Error: /File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/lib]: Could not evaluate: SSL connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate ve rify failed: [certificate revoked for /CN=learn.localdomain] Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet://learn.localdomain/plugins: SSLconnect returned=1 err no=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed: [certific ate revoked for /CN=learn.localdomain] Info: Loading facts in C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/lib/facter/concatba sedir.rb Info: Loading facts in C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/lib/facter/customau thconf.rb Info: Loading facts in C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/lib/facter/facterdo td.rb Info: Loading facts in C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/lib/facter/ip6tables version.rb Info: Loading facts in C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/lib/facter/iptables persistentversion.rb Info: Loading facts in C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/lib/facter/iptables version.rb Info: Loading facts in C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/lib/facter/peversio n.rb Info: Loading facts in C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/lib/facter/postgres defaultversion.rb Info: Loading facts in C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/lib/facter/puppetdb serverstatus.rb Info: Loading facts in C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/lib/facter/puppetva rdir.rb Info: Loading facts in C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/lib/facter/roothome .rb Info: Loading facts in C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/lib/facter/windows.r b Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: SSLconnect returned=1 err no=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed: [certific ate revoked for /CN=learn.localdomain] Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run Error: Could not send report: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read se rver certificate B: certificate verify failed: [certificate revoked for /CN=lear n.localdomain]`be

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess that your certificate is not well removed from the master.

To clean the clients certificate, you need to run the following commands:

- On the master: `puppet cert -c <hostname>`
- On the clients: `rm -rf /var/lib/puppet/ssl` (assuming that your ssl certificate are in this location)

Source: http://inuits.eu/blog/puppet-sslv3-alert-certificate-revoked

Hope this helps.

Comment: This helped : my certs were at /etc/puppet/ssl

Comment: On the clients, rm -rf ... is a bit brutal.
Try with:

find /var/lib/puppet/ssl -name <client hostname> -delete

first

Comment: What you are saying would remove the cert authority too.  Instead rm  slave.lan.pem but not ca.pem in ~/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl/certs